# jquery table href selected all should only select clicked row

Tags: javascript, jquery

Jquery creates a table with href. When a row is selected the on click script processes all the row. Should only process the clicked row.
What should be changed so only the clicked row is selected.

```js
 $("#attachedfiles").append("<tr><td>" + event.name + "</td><td><a href='javascript:;' >[x]</a></td></tr>");
```

```js
$(document).on("click", "#attachedfiles", function ()
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear, and what little code there is isn't well formatted and seems half-completed. Could you edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Edit your question.

Comment: your going to want to use a class versus an ID.  And use the 'this' keyword for your click function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using `$(this)`

```js
$("#attachedfiles").append("<tr class='someClass'><td>" + "Some Name" + "</td><td><a href='javascript:;' >[x]</a></td></tr>");
$(document).on("click", "#attachedfiles tr", function() {
  console.log($(this).attr('class'))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="attachedfiles"></table>
```

Comment: Success this worked. I did try class before but it never fired. All the questions I read indicated #attachfiles.a was the solution. So it should be  #attachfiles tr. Thanks